# How to debug DayDream functionality on Emulator?

Tags: android

I'm trying to debug DayDream in emulator but I have no idea how to do it.

[image: Day Dream Configuration Screen]

Button Start Now does not work for both my and built in DayDreams.

Comment: It started working after some time.

I went to Developer option, turned off Start Awake, then waited till display went to sleep and day dream started. 

Then I went to screen on picture above and Start Now button started to work. 

Then I went back to Developer Options turned on Stay Awake and it sill still working. 

I have no idea why it didn't work.

Comment: Not sure why "Start Now" wasn't working for you, but it's probably easier to debug your code in an Activity anyway.

Comment: @dsandler What do you mean? There is some intent that I can start DayDream service demo?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being clear. The Daydream API is intended to be as similar to Activity as possible, so that it's straightforward to abstract your drawing/animation/whatever into functions or classes that can be used both in an Activity (for development & debugging) and the final DreamService that will actually run during Daydream.